# Remove subview and send control back

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I am invoking "HelpviewController" from `UIViewController` using following code, which is working fine.

```
self.pageViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"InnerHelpPageViewController"];
            self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;

            InnerHelpViewController *startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
            NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];
            [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

            // Change the size of page view controller
            self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 30);

            [self addChildViewController:_pageViewController];
            [self.view addSubview:_pageViewController.view];
            [self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Inside my new controller `InnerHelpViewController` I have done button which should remove this newly added view and send control back to initiated page.

```
- (IBAction)unwindToMenuFromInnerHelp:(id)sender {
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

This call removing the newly added view, but the problem is "MenuController" is frozen. I couldn't do any clicks on it. Any help?

To explain flow--> I have menu screen where one button with name "help" --> When user clicks on this help button first snippet of code in this question executes and shows HelpViewController-->Once done with help, user clicks "Done" button--> Which should close the HelpViewController and move to "menu" screen.

Comment: Don't do     [self.view removeFromSuperview]; . Its ugly. Use delegates yeah back reference strategy for removing view.

Comment: @Tirth: Thanks for your comment! Can you please help me with one reference on how I can use delegates for this case? I couldn't find any example for that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement protocol method in InnerHelpViewController.h file class

```
@protocol InnerHelpViewControllerDelegate

  -(void)removeCustomView;
@end

@interface InnerHelpViewController : UIViewController{

}
@property(nonatomic, weak) id<InnerHelpViewControllerDelegate> delegate.
```

In InnerHelpViewController.m file

```
@synthesize delegate;

- (IBAction)unwindToMenuFromInnerHelp:(id)sender {
    [delegate removeCustomView];
}
```

in MenuController .h file Adopt InnerHelpViewControllerDelegate.

```
@interface MenuController : UIViewController<InnerHelpViewControllerDelegate>{

}
```

Now Confirm your delegate in MenuController.m file while helpviewcontroller object creation.

```
self.pageViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"InnerHelpPageViewController"];
            self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;

            InnerHelpViewController *startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
            startingViewController.delegate = self;
            NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];
            [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

            // Change the size of page view controller
            self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 30);

            [self addChildViewController:_pageViewController];
            [self.view addSubview:_pageViewController.view];
            [self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

//Implement here delegate method
     -(void)removeCustomView{
      [self.pageViewController removeFromSuperview]
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! Let me try this.

Comment: It seems delegate not binding to all pages in InnerPageViewController. Delegate getting called only on "first" page button. When I move to next page, "unwind.." method is getting called but "delegate" method not getting called. Any suggestions?

Comment: Delegate is an one to one mapping, so it did not work in childviewcontrollers of pagecontroller so you have to assign delegate object to parent of pagecontroller class. For detail understanding you must read this http://www.alexefish.com/post/522641eb31fa2a0015000002 and https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html Thanks

Comment: Thank you! Will go through those links.